# AdBlock modifying javascript variable

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, web, adblock, extension

I've seen a page where it contains a `isAdblockDetected` variable, changing it to `false` in chrome dev tools everything works.

Is possible to change a javascript variable somehow in adblock or any other extension, before the page has fully loaded?

I don't want to do this everytime, so that is why I want to use some extension

Solved by using:

```
url##+js(set-constant.js, settings.adBlockerDetection, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

uBlock Origin supports various "anti-anti-adblock" mechanisms, including [script injection](https://www.reddit.com/r/uBlockOrigin/comments/7ejl94/how_does_scriptinject_work/). Though the available list of [injected scriptlets](https://github.com/uBlockOrigin/uAssets/blob/master/filters/resources.txt) appears to be hardcoded; you might have to submit the website to the filter list maintainers to fix it for everyone.

Comment: I fixed my problem using ##+js(set-constant.js, settings.adBlockerDetection, false), but this looks interesting. Thanks